# Create an object of the same type as a variable

Tags: python, class

Let's define a few `Event` class:

```
class Event1:
    def __init__(self, id, val1, val2):
        self.id = id
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

class Event2:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

class Event3:
    def __init__(self, id, val1):
        self.id = id
        self.val1 = val1
```

I use a queue which stores event (`heapq`). To avoid using multiple if / else statement, I've compacted my statement with `or`. The result is:

```
event = heapq.heappop(heap)
if type(event) == Event1 or type(event) == Event2:
    # Do stuff

else:
    # Do stuff
```

My issue is that before exiting the statement, I want to reschedule a new event of the same type as the one from my variable `event`.

i.e. in the if statement:

```
if type(event) == Event1 or type(event) == Event2:
    new_event = # Same type as event, either Event1 or Event2
    # Both take the same arguments, 
    # so I do not need to bother with *arg and **kwargs.
```

How can I create an instance of the same type as a variable? Thanks!

Comment: Consider rewriting `type(event) == Event1 or type(event) == Event2` to `isinstance(event, (Event1, Event2))`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Can you explain me asset of the second?

Comment: It's shorter and it also allows for subclasses. (i.e. `isinstance(Event2Subclass(), Event2)` returns `True`)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Well thanks!

Comment: Often a better way than dispatching with `if` statements based on types is to use methods on the classes, so you just call `event.make_new(...)`, and this will automatically call the method on the correct class.  No `if` needed at all!

Comment: @SvenMarnach True I could have implemented this method. Anyway, I feel like the `type(event)()` solution is quite convenient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if isinstance(event, (Event1, Event2)):
    new_event = type(event)()
```

You get the class of an instance with `type(event)`, and you instantiate a new instance from that class with `()`. And you should use `isinstance` instead of comparing classes. Not only can `isinstance` compare to multiple classes at once, it also supports further inheritance, i.e. if you ever do `class Event4(Event1): pass`.

Comment: Damn that syntax actually works?!? Well Thanks, feeling a bit dumb now ^^'

Answer (score 2):

You can get the type of the object, to then initialize another object

```
if type(event) == Event1 or type(event) == Event2:
    new_event = type(event)(some_id)
```

As a side note, I generally prefer `isinstance`

```
if isinstance(event, (Event1, Event2)):
    new_event = type(event)(some_id)
```

Comment: `type(x) == X` is never what you want.  In general, the right way to test for an instance of a type is `isninstance(x, X)`, but in rare cases you may want to check for an exact type with `type(x) is X`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if type(event) in (Event1,Event2):
    new_event = type(event)(something)
```

Make it easier to check weather  `type(event)` is `Event1` or `Event2`